# How to convert bitmap into Uri without using Media...insertImage(..) method?

Tags: android

I am trying to convert bitmap into uri but the code which i am getting from various SO threads is:

```
       public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
          String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
          return Uri.parse(path);
        }
```

There are 3 problems using this method:

1. The insertImage method is deprecated
2. This solution saves the bitmap to user's device so increasing the unnecessary storage on users device.
3. This doesn't works on every device sometimes.

So can anyone suggest me any other solution which works on newer version also?

Comment: A bitmap cannot be converted to an uri. They are different things.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage(android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) say:

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. inserting of images should
>   be performed using [MediaColumns#IS_PENDING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html#IS_PENDING), which offers richer
>   control over lifecycle.

So you can use

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) throws IOException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        {
            File file = new File(inContext.getFilesDir(),System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpeg");
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(file));

            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file.getName());
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, file.getPath());
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 0);

            return inContext.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.fromFile(file),contentValues);
        }
        else
        {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
            return Uri.parse(path);
        }
    }
```

Note : This Code Was Not Tested
Let me know if its worked

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(file)` You could return that as uri right after compress statement.

Comment: You are not checking the return value of mkdirs.

Comment: `file.createNewFile();`. That statement is not needed. Better remove.

Comment: @blackapps It will not work. means any exception any errors?